# Unable to take PrimeFaces p:rating value and save it into the Oracle database

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to use p:rating component, to vote and save the value into the database (if it is already voted to be able to extract the value from the db later). In the Entity i have also comments fields and i would like if comments are already written to add only the vote so i sometimes i make merge instead of persist (if there is nothing for this request written in the DB).
I have the following code in my .xhtml page:

```
<h:form
        rendered="#{not empty userRequestBean.request.hiredAgency.city}">
        <p:rating value="#{userRequestBean.rating}" stars="10"
            onRate="#{userRequestBean.rateAgency()}">
        </p:rating>
    </h:form>
```

In my bean I have:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userRequestBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserRequestBean implements Serializable {
    private Integer rating; // Plus get and set methods
    private TComment agencyComment = new TComment();
    public void rateAgency() {
        if (rating == null) return;
        EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
        if (!em.getTransaction().isActive())
            em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query queryAgencyComment = em.createQuery("select comment "
                + "from TRequest req join req.requestComments comment "
                + "where req.id = :requestId ");
        Long requestId = (Long) request.getId();
        queryAgencyComment.setParameter("requestId", requestId);
        agencyComment = (TComment) queryAgencyComment.getSingleResult();

        if (agencyComment.equals(null)) {
            agencyComment = new TComment();
            agencyComment.settRequest(request);
            agencyComment.setCommentDate(new Date());
            agencyComment.setAssessment(rating);
            em.persist(agencyComment);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } else {
            agencyComment.setAssessment(5);
            em.merge(agencyComment);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }
```

But onRate, the method rateAgency is not executed. It is executed only once when the page is rendered. How can i implement this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `onRate` defines a JavaScript (client side) action, whilst you are trying to run a server method. 
You need an ajax action instead:

```
<p:rating value="#{userRequestBean.rating}" stars="10" >
    <p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{userRequestBean.rateAgency()}" />
</p:rating>
```

**Useful links**:

- [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/rating.xhtml)
- A good JSF Tutorial (like [Oracle's Java EE 7 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm))

Comment: Thank you for your response but my method is still not executed. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I see you have accepted my answer. Were you able to have the listener called, at the end?